# Images as Plane turned Wireframe

Tags: shaders, wireframe

Working along merrily when some accidental keyboard press really muxed things up. I've imported two images as planes, for a front view and a side view. They were, when switching to rendered or Material Preview shading modes, perfectly usable some moments prior.

However now, it's like I am perpetually viewing the two in Wireframe mode. That is, my images as planes, which functioned perfectly, now seem fixed in wireframe regardless of the chosen Shading(the one accesses with the Z hotkey on the keyboard in 2.8+).

I can no longer see my images.

Thoughts?

Gif illustrating the issue:

https://gyazo.com/829774d112c9b1e4e47f0511ab959366

A final note, I've gone into object Properties and verified that under *Viewport Display* the setting *Display As* is set to Textured.

[image]

For the moment I'm going to re-import the images and clone the appropriate dims/rot/scale/pos values from the anomalous set. Couldn't say what happened here to be honest but thanks all the same.

Comment: have you checked if X Ray is not enabled in the Viewport Shading panel? Sometimes it happens even if the X Ray Toggle is off, I don't know why...

Comment: Heyo moon, thanks for this and the below reply- no dice on the X Ray, toggled that a few times before posting wondering if as much was going on, and gave it a few toggles just now again to no avail. Just in case I'm going about it wrong, the icon I'm toggling is the one in the upper right hand corner of the main/center viewport and located immediately to the left of 4 spehres which represent the different Viewport Shading modes.

Comment: also check the one in the Viewport Shading panel

Comment: https://gyazo.com/76ca092077d05ce048b3a0d445eee0a6

This one? Didn't see an option for it there.

Comment: when you are in Solid mode? Maybe pack your images and share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

In "Object Data" properties, please check that :

- Only Axis Aligned isn't checked
- Opacity isn't set to 0

[image]

Comment: if he's talking about an Image as Plane he should not have this panel

Comment: you're right, I answered too quickly ; you can see in the gif he's not using Background or Reference images

Comment: Thank you all the same.